# In how many ways can we divide the numbers $1,2,3,\dots,12$ into four groups, each containing three numbers whose sum is divisible by three?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> In how many ways can we divide the numbers $1,2,3,\dots,12$ into four groups, each containing three numbers whose sum is divisible by three?

We can group the three numbers as:-
$$\begin{equation}
S_1 = \{1,4,7,10\}\\
S_2 = \{ 2,5,8,11\}\\
S_3 = \{ 3,6,9,12\}\end{equation}$$
$x,y,z$ are terms of $S_1,S_2,S_3$
$x+y+z \equiv 0(mod \,3)$

The only possible situations are

1. All of them are from the same set.
2. One from each of the $3$ sets. For example: $x\in S_0, \, y\in S_1, \, z\in S_2$
   How to find the permutations for grouping them?

Comment: You wrote $S_2$ twice, is that a typo?

Comment: So can you think which arrangements will work overall - how can your possibilities be combined?

Answer (score 1):

**CASE $1$**:Select three elements from $S_1$,they form a group,similarly with ${S_2}$,$S_3$ .now you are left with 3 elements each from $S_1$,$S_2$,$S_3$ and these three also,form a group.

**CASE $2$**:select $1$ element from each of the sets and they form a group.

I hope you can continue with the numbers.